# Getting error in authorization code in linkedin API

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I have tried this but it is giving error:
from linkedin import linkedin

```
API_KEY = '8xxxxxxxxxx'``
API_SECRET = '0Rxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, 
RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print (authentication.authorization_url)  
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

The URL which i get through this print command is showing an error.
Error is in this picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n81Jg4hXITzIraOLpAENUeYpovaHPSfa

Comment: What error? Please update your question the traceback.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass in only those permissions that you selected in linkedin developer console. Try doing:

```
PERMISSIONS = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'] 
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, 
RETURN_URL, PERMISSIONS)
...

print authentication.authorization_url ## open this in browser
```

Once you grant access to the application, you will be redirected to the **RETURN_URL** you provided with `code` query param, something like:

> http://localhost:8000/?code=SDFKSDiodf8ayfjkdf45....

the authorization code is value of **code** param in above url, so to get access token, you can then do

```
authentication.authorization_code = '<value-of-code-param-in-url>'
accessToken = authentication.get_access_token()
```

Comment: I have one more doubt  i.e., how to get the actual token value. I have used this command but it is showing error: authentication.authorization_code = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
authentication.get_access_token()

Comment: I have done the same thing but i am getting error:    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YWc7t24w8honw3iIO5OlD1la_WA0Zt4o